# Parsing JSON arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, json, parsing

I am writing a server-client program. The server is written in C++ and I use JSON strings to send the data. [This library](http://code.google.com/p/jsonplus/) helps me a lot and everything works, but I have one question: How can I parse a JSON array of strings to a normal C++ array? I searched for methods in the documentation, but didn't find any. Do I have to write my own function?

Example, where `s` is the JSON string `{"msg":"message", "content":["content1", "content2"]}`:

```
CJsonObject *obj = CJsonParser::Execute(s); 
string msg = (*obj)["msg"]->ToString();
string content = (*obj)["content"]->ToString();
cout << msg << endl; // message
cout << content << endl; // ["content1", "content2"]
```

But I want an array/vector of "content1", "content2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `CJsonObject::operator[]` returns a `const CJsonValue*` which may point at an object with dynamic type `CJsonArray`. That is `(*obj)["content"]` returns a pointer to an object of type `CJsonArray`. You can do a `dynamic_cast<CJsonArray*>` to make sure.

`CJsonArray` has a member function called `GetValue` which takes an `std::vector<CJsonValue*>` by reference and fills it up with the values from the array.

So you can do something like (untested):

```
if (auto array = dynamic_cast<const CJsonArray*>((*obj)["content"])) {
  std::vector<CJsonValue*> vec;
  array->GetValue(vec);
  for (auto& value : vec) {
    std::cout << value->ToString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Or the C++03 equivalent:

```
if (const CJsonArray* array = dynamic_cast<const CJsonArray*>((*obj)["content"])) {
  typedef std::vector<CJsonValue*> ValueVector;
  ValueVector vec;
  array->GetValue(vec);
  for (ValueVector::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
    std::cout << (*it)->ToString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the real type of a Json Object and use a cast for retreving a `CJsonArray` object.

After the dynamic cast, your object resulting is a `CJsonArray`, wich has a method for that: `getValue`.

```
if (content.getType() == JV_ARRAY) {
  std::vector <CJsonValue*> values;

  (dynamic_cast<CJsonArray*>(content))->getValue(values);

}
```

The `value` vector contain `CJsonValue`, so you can use `ToString()` for each elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using boost::spirit for this purpose could be a viable option. JSON is a pretty easy thing to parse with it and you will be able to fill up your array with interaction with boost::phoenix.